# UFW Firewall not working?

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw

I opened up port 8887 on a server that had it disabled using `ufw allow 8887/tcp`.

I'm not trying to close it again. I used `ufw status numbered` to get a list of rules and then `ufw delete <NUMBER>`.

The problem is that I can still see the web portal on port 8887 when I'm expecting it to be closed.

When I run `ufw status` I get back:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         LIMIT       Anywhere                  
2376/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8140/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
32793/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
9000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8887                       REJECT      Anywhere                  
8887/tcp                   REJECT      Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)             
2376/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
32793/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
9000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8887 (v6)                  REJECT      Anywhere (v6)             
8887/tcp (v6)              REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
```

How can I make sure no one can access port 8887?

Comment: According to the information you have provided port `8887` is rejecting all traffic. If you use `nc -z [host] [port]` you can check to see if the port is open. Here is the [man page for more info](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc). `nmap` is a good tool to check if ports are open as well.

Comment: @kemotep according to `nc` the port is open, as if the ufw rules aren't actually working.

Comment: Odd, I see your answer points out that it was a conflict between your VPS provider's configurations and your firewall. Glad to hear there was a solution, however that is not encouraging that Digital Ocean can leave ports open without your knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might have been caused by the fact that I was using a pre-configured droplet from Digital Ocean labeled Ubuntu 16.04 with Docker pre-installed.

One of the aspects setup was firewall which allows 2 ports needed by Docker Swarm and 22 for ssh.

I'm thinking when I tried to setup my own firewall settings on the node it some how conflicted with their setup.

I went to the node configuration on the Digital Ocean GUI and was able to add Firewall settings to accomplish what I was looking for.

Comment: ufw and docker bought edit iptables and docker wins see more at 

https://blog.viktorpetersson.com/2014/11/03/the-dangers-of-ufw-docker.html